# Taylor series of a power series.

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

Consider a power series $f(x)$ around a point $c \neq 0$. Then is it equal to its Taylor series around $0$? The reason I am wondering about this is because if it is true even for some special cases, then it means there is a power series around $c \neq 0$ which is also a power series around $0$. Then if $f(a)$ converges for some $a$, it implies $f$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $(-a, a)$ and $(c - a, c + a)$ which is counter intuitive.

Comment: What is the domain of your function $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by $\sum a_nx^n=\sum b_n(x-c)^n$ you mean rhat the series converge to the same **function** $f(x)$, then we can take for example $f(x)=x^{17}$, or $f(x)=e^x$, and $c$ any non-zero number.

Comment: Ok. What I find strange is this. Suppose they converge for $x = a$. Let $b = a - c$. Then the right side shows that the series converges uniformly for $-b < x - c < b$ while the left side shows it converges uniformly for $-a < x < a$.

Comment: In the two examples that I gave, there is uniform convergence in any finite interval.

Comment: So if $f(x) = \sum b^n(x - c)^n$ is not uniformly convergent in any finite interval (I guess that would mean a finite radius of convergence around $c$), then would it still equal its Taylor series around $0$?

Comment: If the intervals of convergence do not overlap, we can say nothing useful, since the effective domains of the series are disjoint.

Comment: But if the domain of $f(x) = \sum b_n(x - c)^n$ is $(c - R, c + R)$ and the Taylor series converges outside this open interval, then how can we say that $f$ is equal to its Taylor series?

Comment: That's exactly right, that is why we can say nothing useful if the intervals of convergence do not overlap.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. There has been a fair amount of work done on analogous problems in complex variables.